# How to clone/load special data mentioned in gitignore from master

Tags: python, git, gitignore

I want to keep files in my git master, which should not be downloaded when the git is cloned. Only running an additional script should download these optional files (some trained models).
Is there any git way (e.g. a special command)/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: How exactly is this related to python?

Comment: The code in the repo is mostly Python code. I thought there might be a pythonic way to solve this (e.g. with nice Python download scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to keep files in my git master, which should not be downloaded when the git is cloned.

Impossible. Either store the files in a different branch or in an entirely different repository from where a script will clone them.